# How to inspect TCP/IP packets

Tags: macos, terminal, tcp

How can I inspect IP packets send through currently open TCP connections?
I opened a `nettop` utility in Terminal, which I think lists IP packet, but doesn't tell anything about their content, namely about TCP Data Stream. Any clues? I found the source and destination ports and some other data that doesn't look like http messages. I would like to see how stuff works for educational purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inspect network packets with [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

This software capture all packets through a network interface, although you can select only the protocol you want by applying a filter in its settings.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, you can use the built in command line tool `tcpdump`. You will need root privileges to use it (so execute it with the `sudo` command) - e.g. to see all IP traffic going through your interface, without listening to all other hosts' traffic, you can run:

```
sudo tcpdump -i en0 -p -vv -A ip
```

If you want to limit the output of `tcpdump` to only show traffic to/from a particular host or IP range, you can do:

```
sudo tcpdump -i en0 -p -vv -A ip and host 192.0.2.123
```

or

```
sudo tcpdump -i en0 -p -vv -A ip and net 192.0.2.0/24
```

Read more about `tcpdump` by running `man tcpdump` in your Terminal.